# ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout" on path

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I was working with some libraries so I had to edit Gradle settings. Since my app wasn't working, I restored it with Local history in Android studio but It still doesn't work. Errors returned are reported here

```
05-04 23:26:34.953 28017-28017/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
05-04 23:26:35.217 28017-28017/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop-2/lib/arm
05-04 23:26:35.233 28017-28017/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
05-04 23:26:35.333 28017-28017/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
05-04 23:26:35.465 28017-28017/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


                                                                              --------- beginning of crash
05-04 23:26:35.466 28017-28017/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.quintabi.facchini.myshop, PID: 28017
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.quintabi.facchini.myshop/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop.index}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                                                                               Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop-2/lib/arm, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
                                                                                  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                                                  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:609)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:964)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:994)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:854)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
                                                                                  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:292)
                                                                                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
                                                                                  at com.quintabi.facchini.myshop.index.onCreate(index.java:25)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
05-04 23:26:35.467 28017-28017/com.quintabi.facchini.myshop E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Build.gradle (Project):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Build.gradle(module):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.quintabi.facchini.myshop"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Settings.gradle is just

```
include ':app'
```

Comment: Second line: It says that some file couldn't be found. I'd check that first.

Comment: Says you aren't compiling the ConstraintLayout

Comment: need to see what changes you have done and upload your gradle files if you think thats causing the problem

Comment: @IshaanKumar i imported and then deleted a downloaded .jar package. Which gradle file do you need? As you understand Im total new to android .-.

Comment: build.gradle and settings.gradle. You can easily them access via Android Tab in left under Gradle Scripts

Comment: @IshaanKumar loaded these file. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Changes you have made earlier corrupted your Gradle File (the module one).
It should look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "***" /*Your package name*/
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 5
        versionName "1.4"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
//Your Dependencies
//Don't forget to add dependency of constraint-layout
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
}
```

Add dependency for constraint-layout.
**See Code**

> NOTE : compile has become obsolete and replaced with 'implementation'
>   keyword so replace 'compile' with 'implementation'

so the code will be

```
dependencies {
//Your Dependencies
//Don't forget to add dependency of constraint-layout
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
}
```

> UPDATE: If you have upgraded to AndroidX now. Then you need to use androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout instead of android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout

Comment: If it doesn't solver your problem. Do let me know and if not feel free to accept this as answer :)

Answer (score 75):

You may have updated to AndroidX support library and the layout is referencing the old ConstraintLayout version. So you have to update the `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` tags to `androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout` in your layout XML.

Comment: solved my case too. Since in my gradle.properties file android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true are set to true so it was expecting androidx. components.

Comment: Yes! This happens after migrating to AndroidX. Problem solved. Thanks

Comment: Yep this was the solution. Android Studio doesn't migrate properly smh

Answer (score 1):

use androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout replace android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout, then it worked

Answer (score 0):

If you updated your project to Androidx

Then Change this dependency.

```
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
```

to

```
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout:1.0.0'
```

This will work.